# Soundcloud API Clearing tracks from playlist / set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soundcloud

I have been trying to find a way to clear a playlist/set of all tracks using the SoundCloud API. 
I have no problem adding tracks to a playlist/set, but when I attempt to remove them nothing happens.  I have played around with the DELETE method, but all it is doing is deleting the whole playlist/set.

I have tried this, but the playlist/set continues to have the same tracks in it.

```
# get a playlist
playlist = client.get("/me/playlists").first

# clearing tracks from playlist
playlist.tracks.clear

# send update/put request to playlist
playlist = client.put(playlist.uri, :playlist => {
  :tracks => playlist.tracks
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `PUT`ting empty collection?

Comment: After playlist.tracks.clear playlist.tracks.empty? returns true.  
I also tried playlist.track = {} and still no go.  
And I also tried:
   playlist = client.put(playlist.uri, :playlist => {
     :tracks => {}
})
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The way it works on soundcloud.com is by sending this JSON data via a PUT to `playlists/:id`

```
{ playlist: { tracks: [] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to do it in python:
PUTing just an empty collection won't be enough to clear all tracks from the desired playlist.

```
tracks = map(lambda id: dict(id=id), [0])
client.put(playlist.uri, playlist={'tracks':tracks})
```

This will do the trick and empty the playlist